# SUMIF with multiple criteria failing with <> operator

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a dataset like so:

```
00089   15498   
00789   15498   
10521   15498   
10854   15498   
11058   15498   
11992   15498   
15498   15498   1099755
15499   15498   14321.25
15501   15498   74171.25
15503   15498   4931.25
15505   15498   255521.25
15508   15498   1425
```

I want to exclude certain numbers in column A and sum column C.  When I use a <> operator it sums all of column C. My formula:

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$14,$A$3:$A$14,{"<>15498","<>15499"},$B$3:$B$14,"15498")
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to sum, and what are you trying to exclude?  An example of the "desired output" would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up the syntax.  Try:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A$A,"<>15498",$A$A,"<>15498")
```

It's a good idea to check the documentation for any functions your using that you're not 100% sure on.  Here's the a link to the documentation for [**SUMIFS**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b).

---

An excerpt:

> ## <sub><sup>**Syntax:**</sup></sub> `SUMIFS`
>
> `SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range1,criteria1,[criteria_range2,criteria2],...)`
>
> - **`Sum_range`**    *(required)* - The range of cells to sum.
> - **`Criteria_range1`**    *(required)* - The range that is tested using **Criteria1**.
> - **`Criteria1`**    *(required)* - The criteria that defines which cells in **Criteria_range1** will be added. 
>     For example, criteria can be entered as `32`, `>32`, `B4`, `"apples"`, or `"32"`.
> - - **`Criteria_range2`**, **`criteria2`**,
>   - **`Criteria_range3`**, **`criteria3`**,
>   - **`Criteria_range4`**, **`criteria4`**, *etc*……    *(optional)*
>       Additional ranges and their associated criteria. (Up to 127 range/criteria pairs.)
>
> ([Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b))

**For example**, if you wanted to sum all of Column A from rows where Column B is more than 10 and Column C contains the string "Yes", then you would use:

```
=SUMIFS($A:$A,$B$B,">10",$C$C,"Yes")
```

---

### Google Tip:

There is a ton of information online - sometimes too much, and in some cases outdated information or poorly written examples.  I find it helpful to be be specific on my searches.

For example, when I want to find documentation for an Excel function - which is *lots* (even after doing this for a couple decades) - I search a specific way in an attempt to filter out the, well, crap...

- **for Excel Worksheet Functions:**
  *`FunctionName`*`excel site:office.com` like [`sumifs excel site:office.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=sumifs%20excel%20site%3Aoffice.com)
- **for Excel VBA Functions/Methods/etc:**
  *`FunctionName`*`excel vba site:msdn.com`

---

### More Information:

- YouTube : [**Explanation of Multiple Criteria for `SUMIFS`, `COUNTIFS`, `AVERAGEIFS`**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZuBNWMh7VM)
- Office Support : [**`SUMIFS` Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)
- Office Support : [**Excel Formulas and functions**](https://support.office.com/article/Formulas-and-functions-294d9486-b332-48ed-b489-abe7d0f9eda9#ID0EAABAAA=Functions)
- MSDN : [**VBA Language reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/overview/language-reference)

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll take a look at the docs.  Still having the the issuing where it sums the entire column.  Not sure if having headings is throwing it off.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to sum? `<>15499` means "not 15499", which would therefore sum everything else.

Comment: @user1093111 - I added a link to a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZuBNWMh7VM) that shows how to specify your criteria with the *"`~IFS` functions"*.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `SUMIFS` works. Try this:

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$14,$A$3:$A$14,"<>"&15498,$A$3:$A$14,"<>"&15499,$B$3:$B$14,15498)
```

Comment: That seems to also sum the entire column C i.e. 15501,15503,15505,15508